# Select rows where jsonb field in a provided list

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

Say I have table in Postgres with column data of type JSONB. This column, ortholog, contains entries that look like:

```json
{
  "9823": ["ENSSSCG00000004001"], 
  "10090": ["ENSMUSG00000022347"], 
  "10116": ["ENSRNOG00000004692"]
}
```

I am trying to retrieve all entries with `"10090"` whose any member belongs to a list of `ENSMUSG` ids such as `ENSMUSG00000022347`, `ENSMUSG00000022348` .. etc.

Is there a way to make a query like this?

```
SELECT uuid, data ->> '10090' 
  FROM "ortholog" 
 WHERE data ->> '10090' INTERSECTS WITH 
               ('ENSMUSG00000022347', 'ENSMUSG00000022348', 'ENSMUSG0000009422');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to retrieve all entries with "10090" whose any member belongs to a list of ENSMUSG ids

You can use operator `?|` for this:

```
select uuid, data ->> '10090' data_10090
from ortholog
where data -> '10090' ?| array[
    'ENSMUSG00000022347', 
    'ENSMUSG00000022348', 
    'ENSMUSG0000009422'
]
```

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

> `jsonb ?| text[] → boolean`
>
> Do any of the strings in the text array exist as top-level keys or array elements?

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CWKpmKRn)**